# Ember one init for ALL routes

Tags: ember.js

If I want to do something on route init, I use

```
MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function(){
    // do stuff
  }
})
```

What about if I want to run the same function for initialization of all routes. Is there a way to do it globally without going through each route individually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers are good, but require changing application code. In my case I want to use it for switching stylesheets so every route has it's own stylesheet. I need it only for development, and in production I would compile all stylesheets into one and remove the code which switches stylesheets.

In this case I found it's best to put your code in Ember core ( search for `var Route = EmberObject.extend` )

I also realized that for switching stylesheets it's better to have individual stylesheets not for routes, but for templates.

When I find out, I will post how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068433/ember-change-stylesheet-for-every-template

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is. Just use a mixin.

```
var InitializeMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    __init: function() {
        // do stuff
    }.on('init')
});

App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend(InitializeMixin, {

});
```

Just mix it into any route you want to do the setup in. Also note that I used `on('init')` instead of overriding the `init` function. This is a little cleaner (I think) because you don't have to call `this._super()`.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your base route:

```
MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
    // do stuff
  }
});

OtherRoute = MyRoute.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super();
  }
});
```